Integration of the Cosine function with multiple parameters w.r.t the given variable
I am trying to find an analytical expression for the following indeterminate integral:
$$
I(x) = \int \cos(a x + b \sin(cx) + d \sin(ex + f))\mathrm{d}x,
$$
where a,b,...,f are constants.
Regards

Welcome to MSE. I'd probably first look into integrals of the form $\int e^{ix + e^{i x}} dx$ and then use known trig-identities.
